# Angular-cli 1.3.1

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had created my project in Angular2 version 2.x.x, but then I had upgraded it to version 4. After upgrading to version 4, my angular-cli which was in verion 1.0.0 allowed me to generate components, but did not make the required changes in app.module.ts. So for that I upgraded the cli to version 1.3.1. But after that another bunch of problems ensued. On doing

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --live-reload-port 8081`

I got the following error:

```
Environment configuration does not contain "environmentSource" entry.

A new environmentSource entry replaces the previous source entry inside environments.

To migrate angular-cli.json follow the example below:

Before:

"environments": {
  "source": "environments/environment.ts",
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}


After:

"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

On making the change, `ng serve` works not `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --live-reload-port 8081` and even then on c9 I am getting to see that No Application is running.

How do I get it running? Or I'd in fact like to go back to version 2.x.x with angular-cli 1.0.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Environment configuration does not contain "environmentSource" entry.

the new configuration looks different, you can generate new project with upgraded angular cli and just copy the new configuration to .angular-cli.json

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts", //path of the environment file
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts"
 }
```

Comment: Something really weird happened. After I frantically tried npm uninstall @angular/cli from every possible place, when I am creating a new project angular-cli.json is not there.